# javascript template onclick event without react

Tags: javascript, templates, onclick

```
class someclass {


    aclick(){
        console.log("fired");
    }

     render(){
         `<div onclick="${aclick}"> blah </div>`;
     }

}
```

What's the right way to reference aclick in the onclick function such that someclass.aclick will actually get fired when a user clicks this div like it would in react? I tried

`onclick="(${aclick})()"`

and

`onclick="${this.aclick.bind(this)}"`

I can't get this to work.

Comment: So are you using ReactJS or not?

Comment: no, not using react. just javascript.

Comment: Why do you need the HTML string? Do you use it via `.innerHTML` or something similar?

Comment: So if you have a div with some id, you do the following: `document.getElementById('specifiedId').addEventListener('click', functionToExecute)`.

Comment: @Taki And how will the event handler *string* know, what's `this`?

Comment: @DragosStrugar right now I'm doing basically that: with  $j(document).on('click',  someid, {}, () => { //someclass.aclick }); but ewwww gross.

Comment: I feel like the thing you are trying to achieve is non-standard and thus should be avoided (ie. reinventing the wheel)

Comment: yeah. if react can do it, there's a way to make javascript do it. just a matter of how react does it

Answer (score 0):

The react `render` function returns **jsx** not **html**. If you want to return plain text (html) from your `render` function it's hard to call the `handleClick` method but if you return a dom element instead it becomes much easier.

Because the dom element is an object that represents html (much like jsx is an object that represents html) rather than the html itself, we can maintain our reference to the `this` variable for the appropriate `SomeClass` instance.

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  handleClick() {
    console.log("fired by " + this.name);
  }

  render() {
    const html = `<div> blah </div>`;
    const elem = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html').body.firstElementChild;
    elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.handleClick();
    });
    return elem;
  }
}

const div1 = document.querySelector('#div1');
const sc1 = new SomeClass('first');
div1.innerHTML = '';
div1.appendChild(sc1.render());

const div2 = document.querySelector('#div2');
const sc2 = new SomeClass('second');
div2.innerHTML = '';
div2.appendChild(sc2.render());
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

It can be done even if `render` has to return plain text (html) but it's a lot messier because you have to add a way to look up the `this` variable.

Comment: interesting idea.